# Subclassing NSWindow the right way

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to add a NSWindow like that:

```
customWindow = NSWindow.init(contentRect: rect, styleMask: styleMask, backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, defer: false)
customWindow?.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0.3)
customWindow?.ignoresMouseEvents = true
customWindow?.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.MaximumWindowLevelKey))
customWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(customWindow)
```

And it shows like it should, but I would like to subclass it.

```
class Screen: NSWindow {

    init() {
        let screen = NSScreen.mainScreen()
        let frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, (screen?.frame.size.width)!, (screen?.frame.size.height)!)
        let styleMask = NSBorderlessWindowMask
        let rect = NSWindow.contentRectForFrameRect(frame, styleMask: styleMask)

        super.init(contentRect: rect, styleMask: styleMask, backing: .Buffered, defer: false)

        self.styleMask = styleMask
        self.backingType = NSBackingStoreType.Buffered
        self.setFrame(rect, display: true)  
        self.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0.5, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0.6)
        self.ignoresMouseEvents = true
        self.level =  Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.MaximumWindowLevelKey))

    }
}
```

And I try to add it like this:

```
let win = Screen()
win.makeKeyAndOrderFront(win)
```

I'm new to this, and spent half day searching how it's done with no luck..

Comment: I'm not a swift expert, but in Objective-C, when you call `super init`, it returns the instantiated object, which you assign into `self`.  So the line would look like `self = [super init]` (Not sure at all if that applies here, just noticing something I observed)

Comment: For starters, `Screen`'s `init()` line should likely be `override init()`...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @rocky Window is not displayed.

Comment: @AO, trying your suggestion cause `Cannot assign to value: 'self' is immutable`.

Comment: @NSGod, your suggestion causes `Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass`.

Comment: @HelloimDarius, did you ever get a solution to this?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5, this will work:

```
class Screen: NSWindow {

    override init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask style: NSWindow.StyleMask, backing backingStoreType: NSWindow.BackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {  
        let screen      = NSScreen.main
        let frame       = NSMakeRect(0, 0, (screen?.frame.size.width/2)!, (screen?.frame.size.height/2)!) //...using half the screen size
        let styleMask   = NSWindow.StyleMask.defaultWindow  // ...instead of a borderless window
        let rect = NSWindow.contentRect(forFrameRect: frame, styleMask: styleMask)

        super.init(contentRect: rect, styleMask: styleMask, backing: .buffered, defer: false)

        self.styleMask          = styleMask
        self.backingType        = NSWindow.BackingStoreType.buffered
        self.setFrame(rect, display: true)
        self.backgroundColor    = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0.5, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0.6)
        self.ignoresMouseEvents = false // ...so you can click on and drag the window
        self.level              = .normal
    } 
}
```

And, for showing the window:

```
    let myScreenWindow = Screen()
    let myWindowController = NSWindowController(window: myScreenWindow)
    myWindowController.showWindow(myScreenWindow)
```

Cheers.